# Construct an IFS $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ from continuous map $F:\Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X\to \Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Assume that $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ is an IFS, this means that $\omega_\lambda:X\to X$ and $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ are continuous.If $F:\Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X\to \Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X$ is defined by $F(\{\lambda_n\}_{n=0}^\infty, x)= (\{\lambda_{n+1}, \omega_{\lambda_0}(x))$, then $F$ is a continuous map. Also, $F\circ F(\{\lambda_n\}_{n=0}^\infty, x)= (\{\lambda_{n+2}, \omega_{\lambda_1}(\omega_{\lambda_0}(x)))$. Hence if for a map $h$, we denote $h^2= h\circ h$, $h^3= h\circ h\circ h$, then $F^k(\{\lambda_n\}_{n=0}^\infty, x)= (\{\lambda_{n+k+1}, \omega_{\lambda_{k}}\circ \omega_{\lambda_{k-1}}\circ \ldots \circ \omega_{\lambda_0}(x))$.

In my research, I have a continuous map $F:\Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X\to \Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X$ . I need to construct an IFS $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ such that $\omega_\lambda(x)= F(\{\lambda, \ldots\}, x)$ and $\omega_{\lambda_1}\circ \omega_{\lambda_0}(x)= F^2(\{\lambda_0, \lambda_1, \ldots \}, x)$, $\ldots$.

I am so thankful if yo help me to know it.

Comment: if $\omega$ is continuous then each $\omega_\lambda$ is continuous too. Do you just mean an IFS is a continuous map of type $A\times B\to B$?. What do the initials stand for?

Comment: @FShrike, Yes. A continuous map of type $\Lambda\times X\to X$ where $\Lambda$ and $X$ are compact metric space. Skew product corresponding IFS $\omega:\Lambda\times X\to X$ is continuous map $F:\Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X\to \Lambda^\mathbb{N}\times X$ is define as  above.

Comment: Indeed we can consider $\rho(\{t_n\}, \{r_n\})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\rho_0(t_n,r_n)}{2^i}$ where $\rho_0$ is metric on $\Lambda$. Then $D((\{t_n\}, x), (\{r_n\},y)= \max \{\rho(\{t_n\}, \{r_n\}), d(x, y)\}$ is a metric on $\Lambda^N\times X$.

Comment: We know that every IFS define a continuous map $F:\Lambda^N\times X\to \Lambda^N\times X$.  What can say about the converse it? i.e. if $F:\Lambda^N\times X\to \Lambda^N\times X$ is continuous map, is there an IFS that $F$ is skew product of it?